# SSL Authentication crashes in iOS Simulator

Tags: objective-c, ssl, ios5, ios-simulator

I'm trying to use the following code to handle SSL connections in iOS. It works fine on a real device and the certificate is issued by a fully trusted CA.  It crashes when I try to run it from a unit test. Anyone else seen this sort of behaviour or know a workaround?

```
- (BOOL) connection:(NSURLConnection *)aConnection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
    NSString *authenticationMethod = protectionSpace.authenticationMethod;
    NSLog(@"Authentication method: %@", authenticationMethod);
    return [authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)aConnection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    NSLog(@"Challenge: %@", challenge);
    NSURLCredential *proposedCredential = [challenge proposedCredential];
    NSLog(@"proposedCredential = %@", proposedCredential);

    NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace = challenge.protectionSpace;
    NSLog(@"protectionSpace = %@", protectionSpace);

    NSString *host = protectionSpace.host;
    NSLog(@"Trust host: %@", host);
    id <NSURLAuthenticationChallengeSender> sender = challenge.sender;
    NSLog(@"sender = %@", sender);

    if ([protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]) {
        if ([trustedHosts containsObject:host]) {
            SecTrustRef trust = protectionSpace.serverTrust;
            NSLog(@"trust %p", trust);
            NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:trust];
            NSLog(@"Credential: %@", credential);


            SecTrustResultType result;
            OSStatus status = SecTrustEvaluate(trust, &result);
            NSLog(@"Trust result: %lu", result);
            NSLog(@"OSStatus = %li", status);

            NSError *error = [challenge error];
            NSLog(@"error = %@", error);

            [sender useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
            NSLog(@"Using credential");
        } else {
            [sender performDefaultHandlingForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        }
    } else {
        [sender performDefaultHandlingForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
}
```

The test case output in AppCode is as follows:

```
2012-03-06 14:35:09.656 otest[5696:7803] About to login
2012-03-06 14:35:09.656 otest[5696:7803] AccountVerificationService - postAccountInfo
2012-03-06 14:35:09.658 otest[5696:7803] POST url: https://secure.example.com/user/verify
2012-03-06 14:35:09.662 otest[5696:7803] Login called
2012-03-06 14:35:09.949 otest[5696:7803] Authentication method: NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust
2012-03-06 14:35:09.953 otest[5696:7803] Challenge: <NSURLAuthenticationChallenge: 0x1b8ded0>
2012-03-06 14:35:09.956 otest[5696:7803] proposedCredential = (null)
2012-03-06 14:35:09.956 otest[5696:7803] protectionSpace = <NSURLProtectionSpace: 0x1b8df00>
2012-03-06 14:35:09.957 otest[5696:7803] Trust host: secure.example.com
2012-03-06 14:35:09.958 otest[5696:7803] sender = <NSURLConnection: 0x1b8d0d0>
2012-03-06 14:35:09.958 otest[5696:7803] trust 0x1d8fb90
2012-03-06 14:35:09.962 otest[5696:7803] Credential: <NSURLCredential: 0x1b8e460>: (null)
2012-03-06 14:35:09.983 otest[5696:7803] Trust result: 7
2012-03-06 14:35:10.001 otest[5696:7803] OSStatus = 0
2012-03-06 14:35:10.011 otest[5696:7803] error = (null)

Process finished with exit code 138
```

Debug backtrace:

```
  thread #4: tid = 0x3603, 0x0039a841 CoreFoundation`CFArrayGetCount + 17, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x0039a841 CoreFoundation`CFArrayGetCount + 17
    frame #1: 0x00dad4f4 Security`SecTrustCopyExceptions + 35
    frame #2: 0x00b318e4 CFNetwork`SocketStream::securityAcceptPeerTrust_NoLock(unsigned char) + 150
    frame #3: 0x00b3a154 CFNetwork`SocketStream::setProperty(void const*, __CFString const*, void const*) + 2754
    frame #4: 0x00b39688 CFNetwork`virtual thunk to SocketStream::setProperty(void const*, __CFString const*, void const*) + 43
    frame #5: 0x00b3ad3b CFNetwork`ReadStreamCallbacks::_setProperty(__CFReadStream*, __CFString const*, void const*, void*) + 53
    frame #6: 0x00429b40 CoreFoundation`CFReadStreamSetProperty + 160
    frame #7: 0x00b3acee CFNetwork`HTTPReadFilter::streamSetProperty(__CFReadStream*, __CFString const*, void const*) + 266
    frame #8: 0x00bd4381 CFNetwork`non-virtual thunk to HTTPReadFilter::streamSetProperty(__CFReadStream*, __CFString const*, void const*) + 41
    frame #9: 0x00b37488 CFNetwork`CFNetworkReadStream::httpStreamSetProperty(__CFReadStream*, __CFString const*, void const*, void*) + 38
    frame #10: 0x00429b40 CoreFoundation`CFReadStreamSetProperty + 160
    frame #11: 0x00b41b88 CFNetwork`HTTPNetStreamInfo::streamSetProperty(__CFReadStream*, __CFString const*, void const*) + 404
    frame #12: 0x00b419ec CFNetwork`non-virtual thunk to HTTPNetStreamInfo::streamSetProperty(__CFReadStream*, __CFString const*, void const*) + 41
    frame #13: 0x00b37488 CFNetwork`CFNetworkReadStream::httpStreamSetProperty(__CFReadStream*, __CFString const*, void const*, void*) + 38
    frame #14: 0x00429b40 CoreFoundation`CFReadStreamSetProperty + 160
    frame #15: 0x00be3e7b CFNetwork`HTTPProtocol::useCredential(_CFURLCredential const*, _CFURLAuthChallenge*) + 125
    frame #16: 0x00bfa9e3 CFNetwork`URLConnectionLoader::loaderUseCredential(_CFURLCredential const*) + 117
    frame #17: 0x00bfa4ce CFNetwork`URLConnectionLoader::LoaderConnectionEventQueue::processAllEventsAndConsumePayload(XConnectionEventInfo<XLoaderEvent, XLoaderEventParams>*, long) + 140
    frame #18: 0x00b228b7 CFNetwork`URLConnectionLoader::processEvents() + 107
    frame #19: 0x00bf716b CFNetwork`non-virtual thunk to URLConnectionInstanceData::multiplexerClientPerform() + 21
    frame #20: 0x00b21137 CFNetwork`MultiplexerSource::perform() + 259
    frame #21: 0x0045e97f CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    frame #22: 0x003c1b73 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 243
    frame #23: 0x003c1454 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1012
    frame #24: 0x003c0db4 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 212
    frame #25: 0x003c0ccb CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    frame #26: 0x00108e40 Foundation`+[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 398
    frame #27: 0x0001a4e6 Foundation`-[NSThread main] + 76
    frame #28: 0x0001a457 Foundation`__NSThread__main__ + 1258
    frame #29: 0x94d8fed9 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_start + 335
```

Comment: Darren, does this code work in Xcode?
What version of AppCode do you use? Have you tried AppCode 1.5 Release candidate build? (http://eap.jetbrains.com/objc)

Comment: I'm seeing exactly the same crash in our teamcity CI environment on Xcode 4.3.2 at the moment. Trying to identify the cause ... in our case the certificate is NOT trusted. Most annoying ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have resolved itself through some combination of iOS 5.1, Xcode 4.3.1 and AppCode 1.5.15 EAP.